# Unresolvable nodeJS installer when run grunt in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I installed nodejs plugin in Jenkins, based on this article:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

When I create a job in Jenkins (i run grunt --force) and run it
i get the following error:

```
FATAL: Unresolvable nodeJS installer for version=0.11.13, platform=WINDOWS, cpu=i386
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable nodeJS installer for version=0.11.13, platform=WINDOWS, cpu=i386
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.pathresolvers.LatestInstallerPathResolver.resolvePathFor(LatestInstallerPathResolver.java:28)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstaller.createDownloadUrl(NodeJSInstaller.java:198)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstaller.performInstallation(NodeJSInstaller.java:129)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:61)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:107)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:205)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation.forNode(NodeJSInstallation.java:60)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NpmPackagesBuildWrapper$2.launch(NpmPackagesBuildWrapper.java:68)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:360)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
```

Where can I look for solution?

Comment: Perhaps this is just not supported on Windows? https://github.com/jenkinsci/nodejs-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/nodejs/tools/pathresolvers/LatestInstallerPathResolver.java#L25-L28

Comment: Bummer, yes it is unsupported. Do you have any suggestions how could I run Jasmine tests through Jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out:

1. In ManageJenkins -> Configure System -> NodeJS(NodeJS installation) you
   have to enter a path to NodeJs executable, eg. "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
2. In your Jenkins job you have to check "Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH" and select
   your nodeJs
3. On Build section you add new "Execute Windows batch command" and enter path to grunt.cmd