# Jenkins/npm: not found/config setup/plugin

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I just installed jenkins(installed suggested plugin) and afterwords added plugin `NodeJS Plugin` but still got same error below. Does anyone have ideas..? very Helpful any comments, Thanks! (I am pretty new to jenkins btw)

Stage Logs (Postman Tests)

Git -- https://github.com/reponame/Api-call-testing-automation.git -- (self time 1s)

```
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/reponame/Api-call-testing-automation.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/reponame/Api-call-testing-automation.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/reponame/Api-call-testing-automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 96d5533737397fdb51e1dd116ec5c0667ebb3752 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 96d5533737397fdb51e1dd116ec5c0667ebb3752
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master 96d5533737397fdb51e1dd116ec5c0667ebb3752
Commit message: "First Commit"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 96d5533737397fdb51e1dd116ec5c0667ebb3752 # timeout=10
```

Shell Script -- npm install -- (self time 271ms)

```
>[jsonplaceholder_api_test] Running shell script
+ npm install
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/jsonplaceholder_api_test@tmp/durable-25502f6e/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jsonplaceholder_api_test@tmp/durable-25502f6e/script.sh: npm: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to install `npm` on the build agent executing your tests, of course!

I'm not totally confident that you are really using [jenkins-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline), but there it would pretty easy to run this inside a docker container (using an image that has `npm` installed).

Otherwise prepare the instance (probably you run only with the single Jenkins master instance) and install NPM and make it available to the Jenkins user.

Answer (score 0):

you need to config NodeJs from  Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> NodeJS. Should duplicate to: [Unresolvable nodeJS installer when run grunt in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431349/unresolvable-nodejs-installer-when-run-grunt-in-jenkins/24445927#24445927)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar problem,and i upgrade my jenkins to the newest version then it is ok for me. It seems that it is a bug  of Jenkins and it is fixed in the newest version.

[JENKINS-27170](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27170)